# Creating Dataframe columns in python from a multidimensional array in a scalar data format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multidimensional-array, scalar

I have scalar data variables, and I'm trying to create a Dataframe from it. Each zVariable should be a column in a Dataframe, beside each zVariable has 86400 rows (integer values).

`'zVariables': ['Timestamp', 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Radius', 'F', 'B_VFM']`

The last zVariable 'B_VRM' is an array of three values and also I need to get them to be columns in the Dataframe.

```
[[ 14890.7946   8176.8956 -29578.3765]
 [ 14880.6053   8182.9793 -29612.3667]
 [ 14870.5356   8189.2477 -29646.2455]
 ...
 [ 24488.9148    653.4524  34001.9001]
 [ 24455.326     657.2675  34060.0058]
 [ 24421.7463    661.0861  34117.9878]]
```

To create the dataframe I'm using this code., the challenge is, I need to include the columns from the zVarible with the three dimensions. I have tried numpy, and set of loops, but seems to be more complicated than actually should be., Any advice, or way to tackle this issue?

```
import pandas as pd


dfSatA = pd.DataFrame({'LatA':SatA.varget('Latitude'), 'LongA':SatA.varget('Longitude'), 'Fa':SatA.varget('F'), 'Ta':SatA.varget('Timestamp')})
```

the varget fuction isto get the zVariables from the scalar format where the data is

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Generate random data to experiment on

```
Lat = np.random.rand(7,1)
Long = np.random.rand(7,1)
B_VRM = np.random.rand(7,3)
```

Concatenate all data on the second axis and pass it to DataFrame constructor

```
all_data = np.concatenate( (Lat, Long, B_VRM) , axis = 1 )
df = pd.DataFrame( data = all_data, columns = ['LatA', 'LongA', 'B_VRM_x' , 'B_VRM_y', 'B_VRM_z']) 
print(df)
```

[image]

So you do something similar

```
your_data = np.concatenate( ( SatA.varget('Latitude'), SatA.varget('Longitude'), SatA.varget('F'), SatA.varget('Timestamp'), SatA.varget('B_VRM') ) , axis = 1 )

pd.DataFrame( data = your_data, columns = ['LatA', 'LongA', 'Fa','Ta', 'B0', 'B1', 'B2] )
```